# Fill geom_area (ggplot2) with a gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient

I am having some troubles applying a gradient fill to my area plot.

The data is as below:

```
> df
   year  annual
1  1960  0.0100
2  1961 -0.2700
3  1962 -0.3450
4  1963 -0.6508
5  1964 -0.9458
6  1965 -0.2458
7  1966  0.9492
8  1967  0.5383
9  1968  0.6275
10 1969  0.0000
```

I've set up a `colorRampPalette` for the gradient, and I know this works.

```
spi.cols <- colorRampPalette(c("darkred","red","yellow","white","green","blue","darkblue"),space="rgb")
```

With the plot, my aim is to have the fill colours follow the values in the annual column. So as to make it easy to tell that values are within certain boundaries. Right now, the plot seems to think every value it is "filling" is equal to zero, and is thus filling it all in one colour only.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year)) +
   geom_polygon(aes(y = annual, fill = annual)) +
   theme_classic() +
   scale_fill_gradientn(colours = spi.cols(12), limits = c(-2.5, 2.5), guide = "legend")
```

I have also specified the breaks I'd like in my gradient, but I'm not sure how to utilise this. I attempted to use this in values of the `scale_fill_gradientn` but this was unsuccessful.

[image]

```
spi.breaks <- c(-2.5,-2,-1.6,-1.3,-0.8,-0.5,0.5,0.8,1.3,1.6,2,2.5)
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33965018/ggplot-how-to-produce-a-gradient-fill-within-a-geom-polygon

Comment: Related: [How to make gradient color filled timeseries plot in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250542/how-to-make-gradient-color-filled-timeseries-plot-in-r)